# String.Format for currency on a TextBoxFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, string.format

I am trying to get `@String.Format("{0:0.00}",Model.CurrentBalance)` into this `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CurrentBalance, new { @class = "required numeric", id = "CurrentBalance" })`

I just want the currency to show up as .00 inside of my textbox but am having no luck. Any ideas on how I do this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`string.format("{0:c}", Model.CurrentBalance)` should give you currency formatting.

OR

`@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CurrentBalance, new { @class = "required numeric", id = "CurrentBalance", Value=String.Format("{0:C}",Model.CurrentBalance) })`

Comment: @Html.TextBoxFor(String.Format("{0:C}",model => model.CurrentBalance), new { @class = "required numeric", id = "CurrentBalance" })....Is this the style I am looking for?

Comment: @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CurrentBalance, new { @class = "required numeric", id = "CurrentBalance", Value=String.Format("{0:C}",Model.CurrentBalance) })...This is what I was looking for.  Thank you for the help:)

Comment: It is worthwhile to note the currency notation is dependent on your region settings. In parts of Europe you will get `$1.000.000,00` for one million dollars, and depending on the settings you could get `($20.00)` or `-$20.00` for negatives.

Comment: Why the heck the 'v' in `Value` has to be capital?

Comment: This is a hack. It works only because "Value" takes precedence over "value". This shouldn't be the accepted answer.

Comment: Please use Gail Foad's answer instead. There is a parameter overload for TextBoxFor that accepts a string formatter, that is much better than calculating the format when setting it from the model.

Answer (score 22):

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CurrentBalance, "{0:c}", new { @class = "required numeric", id = "CurrentBalance" })
```

This lets you set the format and add any extra HTML attributes.

Comment: Consider adding an explanation to your answer.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The currently accepted answer is a hack. It results in the 2 value attributes, "Value" and "value".

Comment: format specification - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings

Answer (score 2):

While [Dan-o's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6963546/2615152) solution worked, I found an issue with it regarding the use of form-based TempData (see [ImportModelStateFromTempData and ExportModelStateToTempData](http://patrickdesjardins.com/blog/how-to-save-the-modelstate-into-session-following-the-good-practice)).  The solution that worked for me was [David Spence's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21419665/2615152) on a related thread.

Specifically:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C0}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public decimal? Price { get; set; }
```

> Now if you use **EditorFor** in your view the format specified in the annotation should be applied and your value should be comma separated:

```
<%= Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price) %>
```