# MVC DisplayFormat doesn't apply for TextBoxFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I have a currency Model decorated with `[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:c}")]`, it does work (The $ sign is displayed) for `DisplayFor`, but not for `TextBoxFor` in the View.

May be this is a wrong approach for this case and I'd rather go with some JQuery solution, but I am wondering if there's a "framework way"...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define `EditorTemplate` for `TextBox` and override its behavior any way you want, in your example just to show it as currency (if I understood your motives correctly). I think its simpler than jQuery and its a "framework way" as you called it.

There is great example on how to do it here: [Currency Formatting MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10741190/currency-formatting-mvc)

Hope this helps, please let me know if not.

Comment: You probably meant `EditorFor` - also a solution. Glad it was helpful. Good luck.