# Currency for brazilian real - MVC/DataAnnotation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, data-annotations

I need to implement a currency input where the property type needs to be decimal or double and accept the format "0.00,00".

ViewModel

```
[RegularExpression(@"^([1-9]{1}[\d]{0,2}(\.[\d]{3})*(\,[\d]{0,2})?|[1-9]{1}[\d]{0,}(\,[\d]{0,2})?|0(\,[\d]{0,2})?|(\,[\d]{1,2})?)$")]
public Decimal Salario { get; set; }
```

EditorTemplate

```
@model Decimal?

@Html.TextBox("", Model.HasValue && Model.Value > 0 ? Model.Value.ToString() : "", new { @class = "form-control text-box single-line money" })


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".money").maskMoney({ thousands: '.', decimal: ',', prefix: "" });
    });
</script>
```

I also have set on my web.config culture="pt-BR".
The problem is that the input is only accepting values like "123,98", if i type "1.123,98" I get the error message "The value '9.999,99' is not valid for Salario.".
Is there a way to make it allows the dots and comma? I don't want to use System.String.

**UPDATE - The solution**

I finally found a solution! This is my final code:

EditorTemplate

```
@model Double?

@Html.TextBox("", Model.HasValue && Model.Value > 0 ? Model.Value.ToString() : "", new { @class = "form-control text-box single-line money" })


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".money").maskMoney({ thousands: '.', decimal: ',', prefix: "R$ "     });
    });
</script>
```

ViewModel

```
[DataType("Money")] //Money is the name of my EditorTemplate
public decimal Valor { get; set; }
```

Custom Model Binder

```
public class DoubleModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);

        return valueProviderResult != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(valueProviderResult.AttemptedValue) ? Convert.ToDouble(valueProviderResult.AttemptedValue.Replace("R$", "").Trim()) : base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }
}
```

Global.asax

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(double), new DoubleModelBinder());
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(double?), new DoubleModelBinder());
```

This custom model binder is used to format the value before it is sent to controller. I found the solution on this post: [Accept comma and dot as decimal separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14400643/accept-comma-and-dot-as-decimal-separator).

Thanks!

Comment: Scripts should never be in an `EditorTemplate` - move that to the main view. Are you using unobtrusive client side validation (i.e. getting a validation error that prevents your form submitting - in which case you need to reconfigure the `$.validator`), or is the validation occurring on the server (in which case, what is your server culture)

Comment: Just as a comment, you should probably be storing currencies in the smallest sub unit as an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered before have a look at [Currency Formatting MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10741190/currency-formatting-mvc) that [Darin Dimitrov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/29407/darin-dimitrov)
 had provided.
The key is the DataAnnotation's for the field using the DisplayFormat annotation

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:c}")]
```

Comment: If you think its a duplicate, then flag it as such. But this has nothing to do with OP's issue anyway (which is to do with validation)