# Represent string as currency or decimal using razor @Html.textboxfor

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have an ASP.NET MVC App. I am building an HTML table using razor syntax. The page model is defined as

```
@model IEnumerable < DealView.Models.deal >
```

and the model has a property

```
public string price { get; set; }
```

which can be a number or null.

I am trying to get the textbox for to show comma's (ie 1,000,000) or even better currency ($1,000,000). At the moment I am just getting (1000000) using

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            ...
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.price, new { id = string.Format("
                   {0}_price", item.ID) })</td>
            ...
        </tr>
    }
```

I have tried `item.price.asint()` but think the null instances causes problems. Any advice is appreciated. I am not married to the `TextBoxFor` if there is a better helper function to use.

Comment: The first thing I would advice is to change your datatype to `decimal` and then look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10741190/currency-formatting-mvc . As for the nullability: you probably are better of to make sure the model contains 0 values instead of null, or if you want to keep the null values, use `decimal?`

Comment: The problem is the data is held as string in the xml source which I cannot amend. I am reading it into the property like this

Comment: price = xml.Element("price").Value ?? "0"

Comment: (sorry, new to this) but it doesn't like if I change the type to decimal because it recognises the source as string. Any advice how to cast it is also appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could firstly parse the string so the view model is a strongly typed number (int, decimal, etc). I'll use a nullable `decimal`.

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    string theThingToParse = "1000000";
    ViewModel viewModel = new ViewModel();

    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(theThingToParse))
    {
        viewModel.Price = decimal.parse(theThingToParse);    
    }

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

For simplicity you could apply the following annotation on the property in your view model:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C0}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public decimal? Price { get; set; }
```

Now if you use `EditorFor` in your view the format specified in the annotation should be applied and your value should be comma separated:

```
<%= Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price) %>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can change the type I'd use a nullable numeric type (`int?`). Then you can use the built-in [formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
price.GetValueOrDefault(0).ToString("C0")
```

If you can't change the string type then write a custom HtmlHelper extension to format your strings.

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static string FormatCurrency(this HtmlHelper helper, string val)
    {
        var formattedStr = val;  // TODO: format as currency
        return formattedStr;
    }
}
```

Use in your views

```
@Html.FormatCurrency(price)
```